# Why can i not rename the columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
df= get_returns("SP500")
df1=df["Close"]

df2 = get_returns("NASDAQ")
df2 =df["Close"]

asset = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
asset.rename({"Close": "Close SP00","Close": "Close NASDAQ"})
print(asset)
```

i also tried it with

```
asset.rename(columns={"Close": ""Chg_Close SP00","Close": "%Chfg_Close NASDAQ"})
```

and with

```
df1.columns("")
df2.columns("")
```

what is suspicious is that if i print just one of the datasets than there is no column name. But i do not why, because bfore python knew what was df2 = get_returns("NASDAQ") & df2 =df["Close"]

```
Date
2021-03-12         NaN
2021-03-11    0.016169
2021-03-10   -0.044696
2021-03-09   -0.014814
2021-03-08   -0.025117
                ...   
2020-03-18   -0.028696
2020-03-17    0.221267
2020-03-16    0.016338
2020-03-13    0.263508
2020-03-12   -0.070825
```

if i print the last row

```
print(asset)
```

then Column is shown up each but the change of renaming both didnt work.

```
               Close     Close
Date                          
2021-03-12       NaN       NaN
2021-03-11  0.016169  0.016169
2021-03-10 -0.044696 -0.044696
2021-03-09 -0.014814 -0.014814
2021-03-08 -0.025117 -0.025117
...              ...       ...
```

Comment: the rename will fail because both columns have the same name prior to the rename. I recommend renaming before concat

Comment: Seems like get_returns function is returning a pandas series instead of a dataframe

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'  thats right

Comment: can you please tell me the output of `asset.columns` after you write `asset = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1`?

Comment: [253 rows x 2 columns]
Index(['Close', 'Close'], dtype='object') ...i enter my function as a response too, i think its because of the first line within the function

Comment: can you please ttell me the output of `type(asset)`

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Answer (score 1):

> what is suspicious is that if i print just one of the datasets than there is no column name

What happens is that your `df1` and `df2` are `pd.Series` and not `pd.DataFrame`, so you don't have a column name for them (they do have a name though, if you print them you should see `Name: Close` at the bottom of the output).

Probably the best option is to simply create a new DataFrame and specify the column names that you want:

```
asset = pd.DataFrame({
    'Close SP500': df1,
    'Close NASDAQ': df2,
})
```

P.S. And if you want to rename columns in a DataFrame, you need to assign it back to the DataFrame (`df = df.replace(...)`) or add `inplace=True` parameter (`df.replace(..., inplace=True)`, otherwise your original DataFrame is not gonna be updated. If you have duplicate column names, however, it's best to simply set them with `df.columns = [...]`, as suggested in the other answer

Comment: it works! makes totally sense witht the labels. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_returns(file):
    dfcolumns = pd.read_csv(file + ".csv",nrows=1)

    return pd.read_csv(file + ".csv", index_col = 0, parse_dates = True,dtype={"Open": float,
                                                                              "High":float,
                                                                               "Low":float,
                                                                               "Close":float},usecols = list(range(len(dfcolumns.columns)))).pct_change()
#example
```

this is the get_returns function. I had to apply

```
dfcolumns = pd.read_csv(file + ".csv",nrows=1)
```

because the program always responded with these errors

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], yrav[mask])
```

and then b)

```
 IndexError: list index out of range
```